# Glide does not load images from json, I have been checking all examples but there are not still any solutions for me

Tags: java, android, json, android-glide

I use RecyclerView and Glide to load images from my JSON url to ImageView but I cannot still handle it. I have been checking examples how to do this. I think my code is correct but I dont understand what's wrong. ImageView appears empty. Also I added Internet permission to Manifest.

> MyAdapter

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SubNodes subNodes = subNodesList.get(position);

    //holder.tvText.setText(subNodes.getImage().getSrc());

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(subNodes.getImage().getSrc())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(holder.ivNews);


}
```

> MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<NewsCatalog> call, Response<NewsCatalog> response) {
            NewsCatalog catalog = response.body();
            SubNodes subNodes;
            ImageList imageList;
            mainNodes = new MainNodes();

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < catalog.nodes.size(); i++) {
                    mainNodes = catalog.nodes.get(i);

                    subNodes = new SubNodes();
                    imageList = new ImageList();

                    imageList.setSrc(mainNodes.node.image.src);
                    subNodes.setImage(imageList);

                    subNodesList.add(subNodes);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "" + e.getCause());
            }
        }
```

> XML

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivNews"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Check if the subNodes.getImage().getSrc() is actually an image or not by pasting the link in browser and if the link contains https replace it with http and try

Comment: @RakshitNawani links already start with http and they are images, but Glide doesn't load images. I am very confused.

Comment: check the image size that your fetching, may be it is too big to fit in ImageView,

Comment: If it's not a valid url glide won't push it so try ** .error()** so you will know that it went wrong also check the url